# The export wizard link in the waveform overview page does nothing

Tags: redhawksdr

I have created a simple waveform with two components in RedHawk v1.9.0 running on CentOS.  I am attempting to export it for running outside the IDE and thought I could use the link for Export Wizard in the Exporting section of the Overview page (as described on 19.4.2 of the manual), but when I click on it, I get a whirling circle for as long as the mouse hovers over the link, but no new dialogs come up and if the mouse leaves the link, even that goes away.  Why can I not get the export wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be fixed in RedHawk v1.10.  So I do not need any additional help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried exporting the Waveform by dragging and dropping it from the projects view window onto the SDRROOT in the SCA Explorer window? This installs the waveform into SDRROOT (also works for components, devices, etc.), which is the same thing that the export wizard does.
Unfortunately I don't know what the problem with the wizard itself is, but hopefully this will provide a work around.

Comment: I can install it in SDRROOT but my understanding of the export wizard was that it packages up the waveform for installation in other places or on other machines for running outside the IDE.  This is what it seems to fail to do.

Comment: My understanding was that installing into SDRROOT allowed you to run outside of the IDE, but perhaps I have missed something in the documentation.